# What is the correct way to detect whether a script is running in Azure Automation?

Tags: powershell, azure-automation

Developing PowerShell scripts using Azure Automation can be painfully slow. This is helped by using the PowerShell ISE addin which allows you to test run the scripts locally.

However, inevitably, some things will be different when running locally to when things are running in Azure Automation. File paths for example.

What is the correct way to detect the environment the script is currently running in?

At the moment I define a variable asset that I only keep local and don't upload. Then I can do something like:

```
# Check if we are running locally - NOTE: Do not upload the runningLocally variable! Keep it local only
if (Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'runningLocally') { 
    # We are running locally
} else { 
    # We are running in Azure Automation
}
```

But this seems rather clunky and error prone. I am looking for a more robust and reliable method.

I've discovered some additional methods. The machine and user names when running in AA are both "Client", this would seem to be a more robust method?

Comment: Just thought of another method. When running in AA, the temp folder is `c:\temp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Working solution for PowerShell 5.1 and 7.2**

```
if ($PSPrivateMetadata.JobId) {
    # Azure Automation
}
else {
    # Local
}
```

**Update (Sep 20, 2023):** According to [this blog post](https://rakhesh.com/azure/powershell-7-x-runbook-limitations/) `$PSPrivateMetadata.JobId` is now also available in PowerShell 7.2 so the updated snippets should work on PowerShell 5.1, 7.1 and 7.2.

**Update (Jan 10, 2024):** As @scottwtang mentioned '$env:AZUREPS_HOST_ENVIRONMENT' was removed in September 2023 as the Azure Automation backend was changed from using Azure Sandbox to Containers. In an earlier version the snippets contained '$env:AZUREPS_HOST_ENVIRONMENT' which was compared to 'AzureAutomation/' and is now obsolete. The updated snippets support PowerShell 5.1 and 7.2. At the moment I do not know any working solution for PowerShell 7.1.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've changed over the accepted answer accordingly.

Comment: Obviously a more concise answer for running locally:
`if ($env:AZUREPS_HOST_ENVIRONMENT -eq $null)`

Comment: @Minkus Thank you for the hint. That would also work on other environments without any changes (e. g. Azure Functions). 

What's about an even shorter variant like this?
`if (!$env:AZUREPS_HOST_ENVIRONMENT)`

Comment: @Oliver `$ENV:AZUREPS_HOST_ENVIRONMENT` isn't working for me in Azure PS 7.1 runbooks, but does work when running with a hybrid worker

Comment: @swtto It looks like there was a serverside change in Azure Automation. The environment variable `$env:AZUREPS_HOST_ENVIRONMENT` **is empty** since 5 days in our tenant. I double checked it – if we run it in test pane the variable still returns 'AzureAutomation/'.

Comment: @swtto In the last few days `$env:AZUREPS_HOST_ENVIRONMENT` has content again sometimes  (in PowerShell 5.1 and 7.1).

Comment: `$env:AZUREPS_HOST_ENVIRONMENT` was removed in September as the backend was changed from using Azure Sandbox to Containers

Comment: @scottwtang You are right. Do you know any workaround for Azure Automation Runbooks with PowerShell 7.1 right now?

Comment: I'm not personally using 7.1 so I'm not sure. Supposedly the product team has a backlog item for this but no ETA

Comment: @Oliver `$PSPrivateMetadata` doesn't exist in PS 7.2 when running from a Hybrid worker. It's been awhile since I looked at this, I'm not sure if they're still messing around with the backend, but they may have added back `$env:AZUREPS_HOST_ENVIRONMENT`, I'm seeing `AzureAutomation` when running from Azure, and `AzureAutomation/` when running Hybrid

Comment: @scottwtang Thank you for the update! It would be great to know if Microsoft will change this again or if this could be considered as a permanent soltuion …

Answer (score 4):

You can use the username / computer name for this as you've already discovered, or you can check for the presence of a runbook job id:

```
if($PSPrivateMetadata.JobId) {
   # in Azure Automation
}
else {
   # not in Azure Automation
}
```

Comment: This does not work for PowerShell 7.1 runtime on Azure

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a "correct way", but if you want to check if you're running a script in Powershell ISE you could check if the `$psISE`-variable exists.

```
#same as if($psISE -ne $null) {...  
if($psISE) {
    #In PowerShell ISE
} else {
    #PowerShell console or Azure Automation
}
```

Comment: Ah, OK, do it the other way round - I get it.

Comment: This depends on your development environment. When working in VS Code `$psISE` is empty. But (as you said) if you work with PowerShell ISE this solution is short and fine. 

Comment: True, then you'd use `$psEditor` :)